# Adding two lists together with duplicates C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have **3 lists** of product entity keys that I want to put together into **one big list**. I want the **duplicates present** as I want to determine which product is mentioned most in the final list.

I am currently trying to use .Union but this removes duplicates from the final list.

```
//Union selector results
IQueryable<ProductModel> unionProducts = categoryProducts.Union(attOptProducts);

if (manufacturerProducts != null) 
    unionProducts = unionProducts.Union(manufacturerProducts);

if (brandProducts != null) 
    unionProducts = unionProducts.Union(brandProducts);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894.aspx) instead of `Union` to keep duplicates:

```
        IQueryable<ProductModel> unionProducts = categoryProducts.Concat(attOptProducts);
        if (manufacturerProducts != null)
            unionProducts = unionProducts.Concat(manufacturerProducts);
        if (brandProducts != null) 
            unionProducts = unionProducts.Concat(brandProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done by **.AddRange()** method

```
IQueryable<ProductModel> unionProducts = categoryProducts.AddRange(attOptProducts);
        if (manufacturerProducts != null) unionProducts = unionProducts.AddRange(manufacturerProducts);
        if (brandProducts != null) unionProducts = unionProducts.AddRange(brandProducts);
```